# Was the sorting changed?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, sorting

I just saw a few questions where the accepted answer was not the top answer when sorting by votes. I think that was always the case a few days ago.

Did the sorting system change?

Comment: That was probably an accepted self-answer.

Comment: It's not new that accepted self-answers aren't pinned.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The examples I looked at were self-answers.

Comment: Correct, that's the case, I just didn't notice it.

Comment: That's not trivial, this is valid support question. (in response to downvotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples I looked at were self-answers that don't get pinned to the top.

This was also the case earlier, I just happened to see a few of those cases in a row.